# overflow counter for 3 digits numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a table that I grab the id to create a text field like YYYY_III. where "I"'s are the 3 digit number from 001 to 999.

Given that the ids will eventually get to 1000 and the counter should also reset on the year flip.

Does anybody knows how to handle both situations? when creating I new item I can always check the last created item date and id. But I wanted to handle only the date.

And for any given number let the function handle, instead of checking every time if the number passed 1000 or not.

Something like somefunc(1002, 3) => 003

for the leading zeros I know that we can use a simple pad function.
My issue is math apparently...

EDIT:
Answering to Nina, I came with this: but for example it won't work for 1998.

```
function toDigits (n, d) {
    d = (1).toString().repeat(d)*9
   if (n %  d > 0) {
        return n % d - (n / d).toFixed() + 1
    }
    return n
}
```

Comment: what is a year flip? in terms of code?

Comment: So you want to generate N textfields where N is the amount of days from January 1st?

Comment: @Nina year flip is like last item was 2020_002, let's current created item is in 2021 so it should be 2021_001.

Comment: please add some more use cases and your try.

Comment: @Jon given the year and the current id of the item I just want a function to handle to 3 digits generation so I can ask the function to do func(3000, 3) and get "004" is my post unclear? or did not get your question?

Comment: @Nina, added some code. please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want. It generates a max value and increments the delty of value and max.

```js
function toDigits(n, d) {
    const max = 10 ** d;
    
    return (n >= max
            ? n - max + 1
            : n
        )
        .toFixed(0)
        .padStart(d, 0);
}

console.log(toDigits(1002, 3)); // 003
```